# Django - filter with parameter in generic.ListView

Tags: listview, parameter-passing

tried passing a parameter to a generic.ListView to generate a queryset without getting the intended result.

In my models.py I defined the following three models

```
class Center(models.Model):
    CenterName = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False)
    CenterStr = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    CenterCode = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    CenterRemarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  
    Project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
      return self.CenterName

class Project(models.Model):
    ProjectName = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ProjectCode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ProjectRemarks = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ProjectName']

    def __str__(self):
     return self.ProjectName

class ProjectUser(models.Model):
    Project = models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    User  = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Roles = (
        ('A', 'ProjectAdmin'),
        ('E', 'ProjectExpert'),
    )
    Role = models.CharField(max_length=1,default="E",choices = Roles)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.Project.ProjectName + ' - ' + self.User.username + ' - ' + self.Role
```

then in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('myprojects/', views.MyProjectListView.as_view(), name='myprojects'),
    path('mycenters/<int:pk>', views.MyCentersListView.as_view(), name='mycenters'),
    ...
]
```

plus in views.py

```
class MyProjectListView(generic.ListView):
    model = ProjectUser
    context_object_name = 'myproject_list'
    template_name = 'Procure/projectuser_list.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    ordering = ['Project']
   
class MyCentersListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Center
    context_object_name = 'mycenter_list'
    queryset = Center.objects.filter(Project=2)
    template_name = 'Procure/center_list.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    ordering = ['CenterName']
```

in the template of myprojects/ I put the link

```
 <th scope="row" width="200"><a  href="{% url 'mycenters' projectuser.Project.pk  %}" title="Show centers of this project">{{ projectuser.Project }} </a></th>
```

Now to my problem in MyCenterListView with queryset= Center.objects.filter(Project=**2**)
How can I retrieve the id im MyCentersListView the selected project when I click on the above mentioned link??

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. I Just had to add the function get_queryset(self)

```
class MyCentersListView(generic.ListView):
model = Center
context_object_name = 'mycenter_list'
template_name = 'Procure/center_list.html'
paginate_by = 10
def get_queryset(self):
    return Center.objects.filter(Project_id=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('CenterName')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).